# URL-encoded paths differs by webserver-setup and same rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, routes, passenger, puma

I'm experiencing issues, that Urls with unicode multibyte characters are escaped differently depending on webservers running all the same Rails 3.2-app:

Having this url:

```
"/kautionsbürgschaft-abschließen"
```

On prod server with Passenger + Apache
`PATH_INFO` and `REQUEST_URI` are set to:

```
"/kautionsb%c3%bcrgschaft-abschlie%c3%9fen"
```

While if I'm using Puma (puma.io) or Thin as standalone (e.g. via `bundle exec rails s Puma | thin`)
the afore-mentioned environment variables are set to:

```
"/kautionsb%C3%BCrgschaft-abschlie%C3%9Fen"
```

Note the uppercase and lowercase escaped two-byte characters.

This makes my routes.rb webserver dependant, which I do not like too much. So I'm asking if there is any solution to this?

Regards CR

Comment: I didn't make any progress on this question until today. Somebody out there must have experienced similar issues, or not?

Comment: I have the same problem, but in Apache vs. Pow. Pow = upper case, Apache = lower case. This is with Rails 4.0.0.